# What's wrong with this command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I run this command in Minecraft Bedrock Edition Version 1.19.51 in a command block:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=fishing_hook] ^ ^ ^3
```

The command block reports following error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected "@p": at "execute >>@p<<

I don't know what is the problem with the command, since the command is from a Minecraft command book.

Comment: Syntax for commands can change, which is likely what happened here.  The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/execute) has more up to date information.

Answer (score 3):

The `/execute` command has had its syntax changed to resemble that of Java Edition. The new syntax used to be opt-in, but is now standard for all users. Any `/execute` commands using the old syntax need to be updated to the new syntax to function.

Your command can be written using the new syntax as follows:

```
execute at @p run tp @e[type=fishing_hook] ^ ^ ^3
```

Learn more about the changes to `/execute` on [this article](https://github.com/Sprunkles137/bedrock-wiki/blob/wiki/docs/commands/new-execute.md).

Comment: "The /execute command has had its syntax changed to match that of Java Edition." According the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/commandsnewexecute#:~:text=Note%20that%20the,/execute%20command.), the new syntax does not have full parity with Java, as it does not yet support storing the output of commands or using conditions based on the rotation of entities, among other things.

Comment: @slink Fully aware of this; Updated a word from "match" to "resemble" for better accuracy.