# This command to make my building faster isn't working anymore despite working on old worlds. What gives?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got back to the game and I used this command to make my building faster, and it doesn't work anymore. I'm not sure how to fix it, it's just saying the @e is the problem.

```
execute @e[name="site1"] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~33 ~ stone
```

I'm not on experimental. My old world has it working for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400762/whats-wrong-with-this-command)